# CORS Configuration in s3: Unknown field AllowedHeaders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am setting up a coors configuration in my s3 bucket and I am getting an error when I save:

> Unknown field AllowedHeaders

I followed their doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html which uses AllowedHeaders so I am not sure why it is not allowing me to save this policy. i thought maybe there is a syntax error or something like that but I am not seeing anything. I am hoping someone else has solved this problem before and could advise me on why its not saving.

```
 {
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "AllowedHeaders" : [ "Authorization", "Content-Length" ],
       "AllowedMethods" : [ "GET" ],
       "AllowedOrigins" : [ "*" ],
       "ExposedHeaders" : [ ],
       "MaxAge" : 3000
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The CORS policy needs to be placed in the "Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)" section at the bottom of the S3 bucket's permissions tab.

You seem to be trying to merge it with your "Bucket policy" (which goes three sections earlier)

[image: screenshot of S3 configuration page]